# Why after updating file from example.com/.well-known folder is not reflecting changes

Tags: android, digital-assets-links

I am testing Android Digital Asset Links for deeplinking, uploaded file to *example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json*. But once I tested with **Project1** successfully. Now I am trying to upload assetlinks.json of another Android project (**Project2**) to same host (*example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json*). But server is not reflecting changes. Also I tried to remove file from server from .well-known folder it still exists in file list if I try to visit *example.com/.well-known/*

How that can be possible? Is Google webcrawled the file and showing me previous one? Or there are some standards for **.well-known** folder that once you upload a certificate you cannot change it?

### Update

Another problem with this, first I tried with debug:

[image]

Then I am trying with Keystore it is giving this error(I already updated code at at server at /.well-known/assetlinks.json path):

[image]

Why it is giving error "**We could not associate your app with selected domain**"

Comment: Hi! I have the same issue, and already tried everything, nothing works! Can you please tell me have you solve your problem?